# How to find the background color in Placeholder

Tags: front-end, stylesheet, style

I would like to know how to find the background color used in `Placeholder[abc]`. It is some kind of Yellowish-Pinkish, I think.

There is also a `"Placeholder"` style used by `FrameBox`, but I would like to know just what background color it uses.

We could of course sample a placeholder box with a graphics program, but I would like to find a better way, internal to MMA, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR:

```
RGBColor @ {1., 0.972488, 0.797681}
```

---

Unfortunately there is no general way to track where options are inherited from and from which style etc., but often taking a look at `Core.nb` or `Default.nb` with <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd> helps.

```
core = FileNameJoin[{
   $InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets", 
   "Core.nb"
   }]

Cases[
 NotebookImport[core, _ -> "Cell"],
 Cell[StyleData["Placeholder", ___], ___]
 ]
```

> ```
> {Cell[StyleData["Placeholder", 
>   StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Label"]], ShowSyntaxStyles -> False,
> Placeholder -> True, ShowStringCharacters -> False, 
> StyleMenuListing -> None, FontSize -> 9, FontWeight -> "Plain", 
> FontSlant -> "Italic", 
> FontColor -> RGBColor[
>  0.49321736476691846`, 0.49321736476691846`, 0.49321736476691846`], 
> Background -> RGBColor[1., 0.9724879835202563, 0.7976806286717022], 
> FrameBoxOptions -> {BaselinePosition -> Baseline, FrameMargins -> 2,
>    FrameStyle -> {Directive[GrayLevel[0.79185], 
>      Dashing[{0, Small}]]}}, 
> TagBoxOptions -> {Editable -> False, Selectable -> False, 
>   StripWrapperBoxes -> False}], 
> Cell[StyleData["Placeholder", "Presentation"], FontSize -> 18], 
> Cell[StyleData["Placeholder", "Condensed"], FontSize -> 8], 
> Cell[StyleData["Placeholder", "Printout"], FontSize -> 8]}
> ```

Comment: Thanks Kuba, I was looking forward to this kind of technique.

Comment: @magma Unfortunately there is no general way to track from options are inherited and from which style etc. But mostly taking a look at Core.nb and Default.nb with Ctrl+F helps.

Comment: @Kuba yes there is, see [kglr's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109997/52). :)

Comment: @rcollyer Yep, that I know, I probably should have use that. My point was rather, "you never know where the Background/otherOption you see originates from". So here we are checking Placeholder's Background but you never know if that is not overwriten by FormatType etc etc.

Comment: Ah, good point.

Comment: The moral is that both techniques are good to know

Answer (score 4):

Also:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Placeholder", Background}]
(* or CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Placeholder", "Background"}] *)
```

> RGBColor[1., 0.972487983, 0.797680]

Comment: Great answer too, thank you